Storing arrays in NativeHashMap
I'm attempting to store a arrays of values inside a NativeHashMap.
However, I am being told that TValue must be a non-nullable type. How could I best go about storing the array?
Important points are:

All stored arrays are the same size.
The order of the contents of the array is essential.

I previously found advice online to do the following:
public NativeHashMap<int3, NativeArray<int>> foo = new NativeHashMap<int3, NativeArray<int>>();
However this either never worked or no longer works.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
